# AudioQueueBuffer data turn to ZERO after a few seconds when I using AudioQueue as input with low latency

Tags: ios, buffer, recording, audioqueue

I had a serious problem with the AudioQueueInput. I alloc every Audio Queue Buffer with the size of 512 samples (at 44.1kHZ sampling rate). My callback function is written as follow:

```
void MyAudioQueueInputCallback (
                                void                                *inUserData,
                                AudioQueueRef                       inAQ,
                                AudioQueueBufferRef                 inBuffer,
                                const AudioTimeStamp                *inStartTime,
                                UInt32                              inNumberPacketDescriptions,
                                const AudioStreamPacketDescription  *inPacketDescs
                                )
{    
    ANSampleInput *input = (__bridge ANSampleInput *)inUserData;

    Float32 * samples = (Float32 *)inBuffer->mAudioData;
    Float32 * data = malloc(input.framesPerBuffer * sizeof(Float32 *));
    memcpy(data, samples, input.framesPerBuffer * input->audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame );
    AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(input->audioQueue, inBuffer, 0, NULL);

    for (int i = 0; i < 512; i ++) {
        printf("%f",data[i]);
    }
}
```

This piece of code is written for the test purpose, so I didn't add any other methods. But just this simple code will cause the problem.

When I pressed a button to start recording, the data array is filled with raw PCM value. However after a few seconds the data became all zero.

This problem occurs to me firstly when I test my project in my iPod touch 4. Before that everything is working (the data will not be zero) in my iPhone Simulator (with a very low latency). I thought maybe the CPU of iPod touch 4 is not powerful enough to deal with very low latency callback. But now without any reason my iPhone Simulator has the same problem (also with high latency according to the information popping up in the debugger).

I checked my code and I think it is the same with many sample codes. Now I'm really confused because the Simulator isn't working too.

My initialisation code of the AudioQueueInput is as follow:

```
- (id)initWithSampleRate:(NSUInteger)rate bufferSampleCount:(NSUInteger)sampleNumber
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.sampleRate = rate;

        audioFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
        audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
        audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 8 * sizeof(Float32);
        audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
        audioFormat.mSampleRate = rate;
        audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame = sizeof(Float32);
        audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket = sizeof(Float32);
        audioFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat;


        OSStatus status = AudioQueueNewInput(&audioFormat, MyAudioQueueInputCallback,
                                             (void *)CFBridgingRetain(self), CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),
                                             kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0, &audioQueue);
        if (status != noErr) {
            return nil;
        }

        self.framesPerBuffer = sampleNumber;

        for (int i = 0; i < kBufferCount; i++) {
            status = AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(audioQueue, sizeof(Float32) * self.framesPerBuffer, &buffers[i]);
            if (status != noErr) {
                for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                    AudioQueueFreeBuffer(audioQueue, buffers[j]);
                }
                AudioQueueDispose(audioQueue, NO);
                return nil;
            }
            AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(audioQueue, buffers[i], 0, NULL);
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Please somebody help me!

EDIT:

Accidentally, when I removed the for loop to print every value in the sample array, it works fine, even if I had some process on the sample array. It's weird because the printf shouldn't takes more time than a FFT algorithm. Anyway, it works now.

Comment: Which `OSStatus` is being returned from the `AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer` calls in your callback? Does it change from `noErr` to something else around the time you start getting back silence?

Comment: And when it is running in the iPhone Simulator, the CPU usage and temperature rises and Xcode becomes lag. I'm really confused of which part of my code could possibly cause the problem like this.

Comment: Hi Power Qian, did you find a solution yet? I have the same problem here.

Comment: See the content after EDIT. Try to remove anything cost time in the callback function like print out log in a for loop. Instead, try to copy the array use memcpy, and do the calculation to that new copied array.

Comment: Thanks. I put all calculations in another thread, and the problem is fixed now.